# Implementing New Sass get-map

Tags: sass

I currently have:

```
$site-red:red;
$site-blue:blue;
$site-orange:orange;
$site-deep-blue:rgb(35,106,163);
$site-green:rgb(134,190,92);
```

I want to start using get-map and use my colours more efficiently. I don't have an `each` argument. I just want to end up with:

```
$site: (
    red: red,
    blue: blue,
    orange: orange,
    deep-blue: rgb(35,106,163),
    green: rgb(134,190,92),
);

#footer{
    a.copy-right{
        color:map-get($site, blue);
    }
}
```

Am I missing some syntax?

**UPDATE**

Looks like it was Libsass, it errored out when reading syntax after red (which is probably the comma not being a semi-colon). There appears to be no label with version from what I can see.

Comment: Check your version of Sass to make sure that it supports mappings (3.3+).   If you're using Compass, make sure *it* is compatible with the latest version of Sass (0.12, the current stable version, is not).

Comment: Hi @cimmanon I am on version 3.3.5 of Sass and have tried both Libsass and Sass. With no avail.. I have used Compass but want to refrain from using it for a while. I am now currently using Codekit 2 for this project. Version 2.0.4 (16903)